# Is it possible to prevent Eclipse's indexer from presenting matches for `.class` files?

Tags: eclipse

I'm working on a new Eclipse workspace and my setup is very simple:
My source folder is named **src**, my classes folder is named **classes** and I have in my classpath also the classes from the build on the server located under **server_classes**.

When I use the `Find Type` option in Eclipse it shows me the `.java` files under **src** and the `.class` files under **server_classes**.

Is there anyway to instruct it ton exclude those files by default? (I want to keep them in the classpath - just not run into them by mistake when looking for a particular class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open the Open Type window (ctrl-shift-t), at the top right there is a little black triangle. Click on that and select "Select Working Set..."

You can then create your own working set that only includes your source directory.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Search Dialogue by pressing Ctrl+H, and select the "Java Search" Tab. The "Search In" Section should be self describing.

If you don't see a "Java Search" Tab press the Customize button.

Comment: This is hardly a replacement for the `Find Type` feature (Ctrl+Shift+T)

Comment: but the only way to define the Type Search Scope.

Comment: Not true - look at the answer by leet3lite

Comment: look at your questin and then on the answer. the answer you're reffering to is a workaround. there's no other way to exclude jar's by DEFAULT when searching for types.